# Search terms for changing a portion of the GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface

So I'm building an app for my final class and it involves a lot of self teaching in the programming aspect.  I have no problem doing the research, but in this case I'm having trouble finding the proper terms to search for.  The current project is making the large white square hold different UI elements depending on which button on the left is selected.  Any keywords that can point me in the direction of how to accomplish that is appreciated.

[Home-Brewers Helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOX6i.png)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for Frame/Page Navigation? If you do use a frame, an ugly toolbar will appear on it. You can disable it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059650/how-to-hide-the-navigation-bar-in-a-wpf-page

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using a Frame to navigation between pages. Add the frame to your page and call the frame like:

```
MyFrame.Navigate(new Page());
```

Dont forget to disable the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.